# How can I connect the same ListView-ItemBuilder with different lists?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to programm a grade point average-app, but I dont know how I can make a single grade point for every subject in my subject list. So when i add a grade to a single subject it is added to every subject.

Here are some parts of my code:

```
List<String> subjects = [
  'Mathematik',
  'Deutsch',
  'Englisch',
  'Geschichte',
  'Geographie',
  'WTH',
  'GK',
  'Religion',
  'Physik',
  'Chemie',
  'Informatik',
  'Sport',
  'Kunst',
  'Spanisch/Russisch',
];
...
      ListView.builder(
          itemCount: subjects.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return singleSubject(
              subjects[i],
              () => deleteItem(i),
            );
          },
      )

Different file:

List <int> gradeObjects = [];

...

void gradePointAverage() {
        setState(() {
          avg = gradeObjects.fold(0, (avg, element) => avg + element/gradeObjects.length);
        });
      }
```

On now I didnt now what to do so please HEEELP MEEEE

Comment: "So when i add a grade to a single subject it is added to every subject." Please share code where you add grades to single subject.

Comment: void gradeOne() {
        gradeObjects.add(1);
      }

      void gradeTwo() {
        gradeObjects.add(2);
      }

      void gradeThree() {
        gradeObjects.add(3);
      }

      void gradeFour() {
        gradeObjects.add(4);
      }

      void gradeFive() {
        gradeObjects.add(5);
      }

      void gradeSix() {
        gradeObjects.add(6);
      }

Comment: Please share all code as part of the question and ensure proper formatting.